# Selenium:Unable to click a date inside a Calendar

Tags: selenium

I have been trying to click a date present inside the calendar but i coudnt I have alsao used an explicit wait for the element to be visible but it didnt work either. Attaching an image please have a look and suggest me the proper `xpath` or any other identifer that would work to solve this issue.

[image: Calendar]

I have to click on date 5.

Comment: No one will be able to effectively say how with the information provided, we can only conjecture. Provide at least a link so we can test it. Also, you don't mention what language you are using. We can't guess that either.

Comment: Hi Sorry about not all the info , I have been using Java and the link is as follows http://localhost:8888/index.php?action=index&module=Home , this link will open the homepage and there is a calendar icon right in between of this page,

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you're using Java) you should try using `By.linkText()` using explicit wait as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("5"))).click();
```

Or try using `By.cssSelector()` as :-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#miniCal a[href*='&day=5&']"))).click();
```

Or try using `xpath` as :-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//div[@id = 'miniCal']//a[text() = '5']"))).click();
```